# Check if JSON dict property exists

Tags: python, json

I want to iterate through JSON output using Python and check if specific properties exist. These properties are "network_ip" and "port". If either one or both values do not exist, an error should be thrown.

I can access individual dictionary items using "item["destination"][0]" but, I am unsure how to loop through each dictionary item and check if the value exists.

Here is my code:

```
with open('temp.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
    for item in data["network"]["info"]:
        print(item["destination"])
```

Here is the resulting JSON:

```
{'network_ip': ['172.66.72.44/32'], 'port': [443]}
{'network_ip': ['172.33.48.33/32'], 'port': [1582]}
{'network_ip': ['172.22.24.3/32'], 'port': [443]}
{'network_ip': ['172.49.20.22/32'], 'port': [80]}
{'network_ip': ['172.43.24.153/32'], 'port': [1629]}
{'network_ip': ['172.43.48.34/32'], 'port': [443]}
```

Here is the structure of the original data:

```
network:
  info:
  - action: Allow
    protocol: TCP
    destination:
      network_ip:
      - 172.66.72.44/32 
      port:
      - 443
  - action: Allow
    protocol: TCP
    destination:
      nets:
      - 172.33.48.33/32
      port:
      - 1582    
  - action: Allow
    protocol: TCP
    destination:
      nets:
      - 172.22.24.3/32 
      port:
      - 443
  - action: Allow
    protocol: TCP
    destination:
      nets:
      - 172.49.20.22/32
      port:
      - 80
  - action: Allow
    protocol: TCP
    destination:
      nets:
      - 172.43.24.153/32 
      port:
      - 1629
  - action: Allow
    protocol: TCP
    destination:
      nets:
      - 172.43.48.34/32
      port:
      - 443
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained or showed the structure of your data, at least a sample of the contents of `data["network"]["info"]`

Comment: I have included the structure of the YAML data

Comment: In your question you ask how to "iterate through JSON output", so what good is showing the structure of the YAML data?

Comment: it initially loads YAML that gets converted in JSON

Comment: That's nice, but you need to show what is actually being processed. Note that none of the entries in the YAML data have a property named `port`. Also note that `item["destination"][0]` would never work because `item["destination"]` is not a list.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the output shown is coming from `item["destination"]`, you could try using `in` to check if both keys exist in the dictionary:

```
"network_ip" in item["destination"] and "port" in item["destination"]
```

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect — at least it's not what converting the sample YAML converted to JSON produces.

Comment: Are you sure @martineau ? The result of transforming from YAML to JSON seems to match my assumption and the expected result of this code

Comment: Yes — at least it wasn't when I converted the YAML to JSON myself since the OP did not show that in their question.